# Change data- attr and then get object by data- in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have `html`:

```
<div class="item" data-value="1">item</div>
```

And `js`:

```
$('.item[data-value="1"]').data('value', 2');
```

So, now I have `.item` with `data-value="2"`, I want get it by jQuery:

```
$('.item[data-value="2"]')
```

It returns `[]`

I know that the problem is in the fact, that jQuery changes data values not changing `data-value` attribute. I know, that the problem can be solved by using `attr` method instead of `data`.

But is there any way to get objects by `data` with `data` changed by `data` method?

Comment: where do u see the "fact" that the `data-value` doesnt get updated?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308608/jquery-data-and-attr-weird-behaviour

Comment: The fact is that it *doesn't* update the `data-value` attribute, you can easily test this with some basic javascript.  I've run into similar situations, if part of your code is reliant on the attribute value itself then changing it via `data()` won't work.  You need to change it with `.attr('data-value', abc)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2895933/1185123), you can just write:

```
$('.item:data(value==2)');
```

Comment: It works with jQuery UI and the function from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2895933/1185123. Thank you. The only thing I'm afraid of is perfomance

Comment: No problem, thank you for edit. I havent tested it yet, so I do not know about its performance.

Comment: Frankly I don't like how jQuery's `data()` method silently changes the value but not the attribute (so that next time you call `data('value')` you get a different value than is seen with a CSS selector `[data-value=something]`.  I still argue that Joe's answer is better so that the attribute itself changes as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the elements using `filter` and `data` methods.

```
$('.item').filter(function() {
   return $(this).data('value') === '2';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3dfX7/

Comment: Love this method! I even didn't think about `filter`. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You've closed the bracket false:

```
$('.item[data-value="2"]')
```

should work using

```
.attr('data-value', 2)
```

to update data value :)

Comment: it works, but i've wrote about this method in my question: "I know, that the problem can be solved by using attr method instead of data."